# How to perform Conditional operations on Pandas columns?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe, I want to perform conditional operations on the `MAG` column.

```
MAG MagT
2   ML
3.5 mb
6   MC
5.6 mb
4   ML
```

conditions will be like if MagT is equal to some specific value I have to perform an operation and save the value there.

```
if MagT=='ML' 
  MAG=MAG*5
  MagT=='mb'
if MagT=='MC'
 MAG=MAG*3
 MagT='ML'
.
.
.
else 
 MAG=MAG
 MagT=MagT
```

How could I Do that?

```
output
MAG MagT
10  mb
3.5 mb
18  ML
5.6 mb
4   ML
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.  Please work through available tutorials on PANDAS; pay attention to filtering and conditionals (the `where` clause).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use numpy.where

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(10)
a
# array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
np.where(a < 5, a, 10*a)
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90])

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where
```

and in your case:

```
df["MAG"] = np.where(df["MagT"]=='ML',df["MAG"]*5,df["MAG"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"MAG": [2,3.5,6,5.6,4], "MagT": ["ML","mb","MC","mb","ML"]})
>>> df
   MAG MagT
0  2.0   ML
1  3.5   mb
2  6.0   MC
3  5.6   mb
4  4.0   ML
>>> df.loc[df["ML"],"MagT"] = df["MAG"]*5
>>> df
    MAG MagT
0  10.0   ML
1   3.5   mb
2   6.0   MC
3   5.6   mb
4  20.0   ML
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1, 'b': 2}, {'a':1, 'b': 2}, {'a':1, 'b': 3}])

df.loc[df['b'] == 3, 'a'] = df['a']*2
```